# how do I get this image url to display in flashbuilder 4.5 using BINDABLE and a JSON node value that has urlencoded values

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Im loading JSON in a flashbuilder 4.5 mobile app Im working on, so far all the variables render fine and I am using left and right swipe gestures to allow the user to move through the array of items - using actionscript3.

Now I get to the part where Im working on adding an image to the stage that has its SOURCE parameter bound to a variable (thisimg2) whose value is the json value for the image url...   an example of the URL is:

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTA2MlgxNjAw/%24T2eC16JHJG%21E9nm3pkoZBQDVSKHsow%7E%7E60_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F
```

and

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/%24%28KGrHqV,%21pcE9eMM4r4ZBPmiD+Ft%21%21%7E%7E60_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F
```

a small percentage of the json URL values come back as really simple image URLs with no hex values and those show up just fine, but the majority of the, that appear like the 2 examples above, dont render at all and just result in the broken image/question mark symbol in flex (using desktop debug / emulator).  I tried decode on the url string but that didnt work.

when I put the urls in my browsers they work fine and render in browser.

is there anything I can do to the URL's to get them work?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide an example of a URL that is working for you?

I believe Ebay is specifically preventing Flash apps from other domains from using their images.

The URL encoding is not the problem ... Flash just relies on the browser to download them.  However, take a look at this code buried deep inside the `BitmapImage` component (which is the underlying thing that the Spark `Image` component uses):

BitmapImage::loadExternal() (line 1513)

```
    try
    {
        loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = source is URLRequest ?
            source as URLRequest : new URLRequest(source as String);
        loader.load(urlRequest, loaderContext);
    }
```

Here it is telling the `Loader` that it will use to fetch the image to check the source domain's crossdomain.xml file. Here is a [link](http://i.ebayimg.com/crossdomain.xml) to that crossdomain.xml file.

Their crossdomain.xml file is specifically allowing Flash apps from various ebay domains to access the content on i.ebayimage.com. I just scanned it, but I don't see anything there allowing a wildcard (`allow-access-from domain="*"`) so that non-ebay domains are permitted. So you will never be able to use those images in a Flash app, unless ebay allows you to.

**[Edit]**

**Before you do one of the things below, you should probably [determine the legality of what you're doing](http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/copyright-fair-use-and-how-it-works-for-online-images/).**

Actually, I take that back. You will never be able to use the Flex `Image` or `BitmapImage` components to load these images because those components check the policy file. However, you have a few options:

- extend the `BitmapImage` class and override the `loadExternal()` method so it doesn't check the policy file
- Use your own `Loader` to show the images. This is a bit more work inside of a Flex app, but it works (I just tested it w/a simple AS3 app).

Here's the very rudimentary AS3 application I tested with (not using Flex):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class As3Project extends Sprite
    {

        private var loader:Loader;

        function As3Project()
        {
            loader=new Loader();
            var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTA2MlgxNjAw/%24T2eC16JHJG%21E9nm3pkoZBQDVSKHsow%7E%7E60_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F");
            loader.load(url);
            addChild(loader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding some clarity to this for me.  I will try the loader approach and see how it goes.  Do you care to share the as for the test you performed if you still have it?  Thanks again.

Comment: @tamak Added the AS3 app I used to test.