# Adobe flex as3 get data from imdb api

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, imdb

i'm trying to get data from  imdb to as3.Is all right until i tried set in object image url from "poster". I tried the following:

```
public function loadXML(path:String):void {
            var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+path+"&r=xml"));
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handleLoad);

        }



public function handleLoad(event:Event):void{
            var usersXML:XML = new XML(event.target.data);

            title1.text = usersXML.movie.@title;
            img.source =usersXML.movie.@poster;

        }
```

Images from other sites works in 100%.

Comment: This issue is caused by the [crossdomain.xml](http://imdb.com/crossdomain.xml) that imdb.com has deployed. This file only permits Flash apps from imdb.com domains to load data. Compare that with the [crossdomain.xml](http://www.omdbapi.com/crossdomain.xml) from omdbapi.com which permits Flash apps from any domain to use their data. The Flex `Image` component has code that checks these policy files and this is why your images are not being displayed. This is a duplicate question, check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15178377/398606) for details and alternatives.

Comment: Can't mark this as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15176661/398606) because the person who asked the original question never accepted or up-voted my answer (even though they basically confirm it's the answer)... If you find my answer helpful, feel free to up-vote it :)

Comment: After reading the two questions; I don't think they are duplicate; even though the answer is identical.  The answer I would give is "Use a server side proxy to bypass the client side cross domain requirements"